# T-SQL split result into two rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm building a customer statement report and have the below query.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans AS InvDate
    ,dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strDocRef
    ,SUM(dbo.vCustomerTransactions.intAmountTax) AS Debit
    ,ISNULL(dbo.Cashbook.strTransRef, 'None') AS strTransRef
    ,ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Cashbook.intAmount), 0) AS Credit
    ,ISNULL(dbo.Cashbook.datCaptured, 0) AS PaymentDate
FROM dbo.vCustomerTransactions
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cashbook ON dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strDocID = dbo.Cashbook.strDocID
WHERE dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans BETWEEN '2020-02-01 00:00:00'
        AND '2020-03-18 00:00:00'
    AND dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strTransType IN ('INV')
GROUP BY dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strDocRef
    ,dbo.Cashbook.strTransRef
    ,dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans
    ,dbo.Cashbook.datCaptured
ORDER BY dbo.Cashbook.strTransRef DESC
    ,dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans
```

The data is returned as follows.

```
"2020-02-29 00:00:00"   "INV0034004" "1236.7675" "RCPT0007790" "1236.77" "2020-03-10 00:00:00"
```

What i need to do for that report is split that 1 row into two result rows, as follows

```
"2020-02-29 00:00:00"   "INV0034004" "1236.7675" "0.00"
"2020-03-10 00:00:00"   "RCPT0007790" "0.00"     "1236.77"
```

So its splitting the data into debts and credits. I have no idea how to achieve this, please could someone point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks.

Comment: check out cross apply

Comment: Or an `UNION` of two queries

Comment: Stop trying to order a view. Forget you ever learned about using `top (100) percent` - it does nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some guesses here, especially in regards that if `Credit` or `Debit` has a value of `0` you don't want the row, however using `VALUES` would likely be better here. It would certainly avoid the overhead of 2 scans of the tables, and the costly `UNION` (rather than `UNION ALL`):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    --3 part naming for columns is being removed from SQL Server,. Don't use it.
    SELECT --Removed Top, as pointless
        CT.datTrans AS InvDate,
        CT.strDocRef,
        SUM(CT.intAmountTax) AS Debit,
        ISNULL(Cb.strTransRef, 'None') AS strTransRef,
        ISNULL(SUM(Cb.intAmount), 0) AS Credit,
        ISNULL(Cb.datCaptured, 0) AS PaymentDate
    FROM dbo.vCustomerTransactions CT
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cashbook Cb ON CT.strDocID = Cb.strDocID
    WHERE CT.datTrans BETWEEN '2020-02-01T00:00:00' AND '2020-03-18T00:00:00'
      AND CT.strTransType IN ('INV')
    GROUP BY CT.strDocRef,
             Cb.strTransRef,
             CT.datTrans,
             Cb.datCaptured)
SELECT C.InvDate,
       C.strDocRef,
       V.Debit,
       C.strTransRef,
       V.Credit,
       C.PaymentDate
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (0, C.Debit),
                         (C.Credit, 0)) V (Credit, Debit)
WHERE NOT(V.Debit = 0 AND V.Credit = 0)
ORDER BY C.strTransRef DESC,
         C.InvDate;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much Larnu. Just one more thing, is there a way to "merge" the "strDocRef" and "strTransRef" columns so that the strDocRef column shows both the invoice and receipt number ?

Comment: Use the concatenation operator (`+`) @AlexJames . (I *assume* they are both `(n)varchar`s.)

Comment: If this did solve the problem, please do consider marking the answer as the solution too please, @AlexJames . This lets future users know the answer was helpful, and that your question has been answered

Comment: Thanks Larnu, i'll try it with the (+)

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to take the original query and make it into a Common Table Expression (or a temporary table if you want to do it the old school way). And then do two queries - one for credits and one for debits - off of that resultset and UNION them together. Something like this:

```
WITH cteMain AS (
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans AS InvDate
    ,dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strDocRef
    ,SUM(dbo.vCustomerTransactions.intAmountTax) AS Debit
    ,ISNULL(dbo.Cashbook.strTransRef, 'None') AS strTransRef
    ,ISNULL(SUM(dbo.Cashbook.intAmount), 0) AS Credit
    ,ISNULL(dbo.Cashbook.datCaptured, 0) AS PaymentDate
FROM dbo.vCustomerTransactions
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Cashbook ON dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strDocID = dbo.Cashbook.strDocID
WHERE dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans BETWEEN '2020-02-01 00:00:00'
        AND '2020-03-18 00:00:00'
    AND dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strTransType IN ('INV')
GROUP BY dbo.vCustomerTransactions.strDocRef
    ,dbo.Cashbook.strTransRef
    ,dbo.vCustomerTransactions.datTrans
    ,dbo.Cashbook.datCaptured
)
SELECT InvDate AS TheDate, strDocRef AS TheRef, Debit, 0.0 AS Credit
FROM cteMain
UNION
SELECT PaymentDate AS TheDate, strTransRef AS TheRef, 0.00 AS Debit, Credit
FROM cteMain
```

You might also need a `WHERE Debit > 0.00` and `WHERE Credit > 0.0` in those two `SELECT` statements, to only pick up the credits/debits that have values, depending on your needs.